# Office 2010 and VBA show different font sizes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint template created in Office 2003. When I opened the SlideMaster of the template in Office 2010, I saw that the font sizes of bulleted body are 24, 22, 20, 18, 16 for level 1, level 2, level 3, level 4, level 5 respectively. The strange thing is that when I used VBA to loop through all bulleted text, I noticed that the font sizes for bulleted text are 32, 28, 24, 20, 20 which are quite different compared to the ones viewed in the app.

If I open the template in Office 2003, PowerPoint and VBA show the same result: 32, 28, 24, 20, 20.

I'm wondering why in Office 2010 there is the difference between the app and VBA (Please see attachment)
[image: Font size difference in PowerPoint 2010 and VBA]
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Masters and such are quite different in 2007/2010 from the way they worked in earlier versions.  After opening the older format file in 2010, ignore the slide master at the top and look at the second *layout* (the ones that are indented under the main master).  How does that compare with the original presentation?